# Alternatives to "hard cases make bad law"

Tags: phrase-usage, idioms, idiomatic-language

Are there any alternative idioms or phrases in english, equivalent to the legal maxim "**hard cases make bad law**" best suiting the context of the following sentence?

> I deeply sympathise with the unfortunate victim, but **hard cases make bad law**. It is not the within the discretion of the judge to let sympathy lend weight to the evidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always heard this as *"bad facts make bad law."*

In other words, cases with a particularly unlikable litigant—for example, a defendant who is a serial killer or rapist whose rights were violated by the police investigating them), or from the other side, someone who did horrible things without breaking the law—sometimes result in judges and/or juries ignoring what the law *actually* says and ruling based on what they feel is fair.

In legal systems where the interpretation of the law is largely based on judicial precedent (also known as *case law*), such as the United States, this can set a bad precedent for future cases—hence, *bad law*.